# jQuery multiple click events Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am loading a HTML form using jQuery. The form is a poll and has options to choose which are html radio buttons. The problem, if I click the submit button without choosing an option, the form does not submit which is expected, but... after I choose an option, the form submits as many times as the button was clicked when no option was selected, i.e. click the button 5 times, form is then submitted 5 times when an option is chosen! I am expecting the form to only submit once, when an option (radio button) is selected. I don't want it to submit if not option is clicked.

```
$('#pollcontainer').on('click', '#submit', function() {
  $('#pollform').submit(function(e) {
    if (!$("input[name='pollchoice']:checked").val()) {} else {
      console.log('clicked with value!');
      $.post('poll-ajax.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data, status) {
        $('#formcontainer').hide(function() {
          $(this).html(data);
          $.get('poll-ajax.php', {
            poll: '123',
            result: '1'
          }, function(data,
            status) {
            pollcontainer.html(data);
          });
        });
      });
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: why not disable button if you already send an ajax request? or create an identifier that tells you that you already send an ajax and your not allowed to click that button again ?

Comment: Thanks Rowel de Guzman for your fast reply.

I am stuck at this point. I've tried to disable the button but as it's a dynamic form I'm having problems making the functions work. If I manage to disable the button on the first ajax request and no option is clicked, this will prevent any further submission of the form?

Comment: then you i think the best way you can do is to create an identifier 

var isSend = false;
$('#pollform').submit(function(e) {
  if (!isSend) {
    $.post('poll-ajax.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data, status) {
       isSend = true
    })
  }
}

Comment: Thanks Rowel. I didn't think of using a var as a sent flag. I will give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

You put the `submit` event inside the `click` event, so every time you click the button, then `submit` event is recreated. You don't need the `click` event at all in this case, and the `submit` event will do all what you want:

```
$('#pollform').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!$("input[name='pollchoice']:checked").val()) {} else {
    console.log('clicked with value!');
    $.post('poll-ajax.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data, status) {
      $('#formcontainer').hide(function() {
        $(this).html(data);
        $.get('poll-ajax.php', {
          poll: '123',
          result: '1'
        }, function(data,
          status) {
          pollcontainer.html(data);
        });
      });
    });
  }
  return false;
});
```

However, there is an alternative. You are submitting the form with Ajax, so why do you need the standard form submission in the first place? You can simply convert your button to a normal button (`type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`) and use it's `click` event to submit with Ajax, and disable the standard form submission altogether. Example:

```js
$('#pollcontainer').on('click', '#submit', function() {
  if (!$("input[name='pollchoice']:checked").val()) {} else {
    console.log('clicked with value!');
    $.post('poll-ajax.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data, status) {
      $('#formcontainer').hide(function() {
        $(this).html(data);
        $.get('poll-ajax.php', {
          poll: '123',
          result: '1'
        }, function(data,
          status) {
          pollcontainer.html(data);
        });
      });
    });
  }
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pollcontainer">
  <form id="pollform" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="pollchoice" />
    <button type="button" id="submit">Send</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Racil Hilan. I tried to remove the click function but without it the form submits normally and redirects to the poll-ajax.php page. The return false; does not seem to work without the click function and I don't know how to stop the redirection.

Comment: Oh, that's not a problem, use the `preventDefault()` to fix that. See my updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've left the click function inplace and changed the button to  type="button" instead of type="submit". Nothing is happening when I click the submit button. I'm out of ideas that this point.

Comment: If you want to follow the other way, then you have to remove the `submit` event inside the `click event. I will add an example to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! for you help but I am not able to get this to work. My form is being brought into the page as it lives on the poll-ajax.php page. The only html code I have on the page where the Javascript is : 

<div id="container" >
<div id="pollcontainer" ></div>
</div> 

I think that this is my main problem. As far as I have learned, dynamic form elements are harder to work with. I have just clicked the button 20 times, and then selected a choice and submitted. It submitted 20 times! :(

Comment: But you said that you changed the button type, so you also see the button, not only those two `div`s.

Comment: Yes. Button is type="button" and is on the poll-ajax.php page and div's are on the page with the javascript.

Comment: If I lose the click function and then get the submit handler to attach to the form then it should work, but I don't know how to do this as the form elements are children? due to being dynamic?.

Comment: OK, so what's the problem? You've already changed the type of the button, now follow the rest of my answer. Disable the form submission by adding ` onsubmit="return false;"`, and then use the JavaScript from my second example.

Comment: Yes, if you lose the click function and then get the submit handler to attach to the form then it should work as per my first example. That's all what you need, so I don't know why you said *I don't know how to do this*. It doesn't matter if the elements are dynamic or not as long as they are available when you attach the event handler. Maybe you need to show us the code for the form so we can help you better.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a go in the morning. I can understand what you are saying but I'm having difficulty attaching the submit function, it just won't attach unless I keep the click function. The form is a straight forward HTML form on the poll-ajax.php page.

Comment: That means the JavaScript is executing before the form is added to the DOM. You can change `$('#pollform').submit(function()` to `$('#pollcontainer').on('submit', '#pollform', function()`. Alternatively, you can make it a function and call it in the form HTML `onsubmit="return mySubmitFunction();"`.

Comment: Many, many thanks Racil Hilan. I went with your suggestion to remove the click function and use $('#pollcontainer').on('submit', '#pollform', function()
This worked! I didn't know you could use submit with on(). It now has the parent and child IDs which seems to allow it to bind. Thanks again for your patience and solution.

Comment: Yes, you can use `on()` with any event. In fact, the event functions like `click()` and `submit()` are kind of shortcuts to the `on()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if your form is ready to be submitted before calling `submit` method. Try this:

```
$('#pollcontainer').on('click', '#submit', function() {
  // don't submit if no value entered
  if (!$("input[name='pollchoice']:checked").val()) {
    return false;
  }
  $('#pollform').submit(function(e) {
      console.log('clicked with value!');
      $.post('poll-ajax.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data, status) {
        $('#formcontainer').hide(function() {
          $(this).html(data);
          $.get('poll-ajax.php', {
            poll: '123',
            result: '1'
          }, function(data,
            status) {
            pollcontainer.html(data);
          });
        });
      });
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Still the same result. If I click the button 10 times before choosing an option. The form then submits 10 times right after I choose an option?